# How can I debug my save events?

Tags: emacs, elisp

When I run `M-x basic-save-buffer`, python watchdog's `watchmedo` shows two `FileModifiedEvent`s for the file being visited.  I was only expecting one event.  How can I find out what is causing the modifies?

`write-contents-functions` is `nil`

`write-file-functions` is `(undo-tree-save-history-hook recentf-track-opened-file)`

`before-save-hook` is `nil`

`after-save-hook` is `(executable-make-buffer-file-executable-if-script-p)`.

The file being visited is not a script / not executable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could run the emacs process through `strace` to see the syscalls it makes.

`strace` generates a lot of output, so you'll want to use `strace -o trace=file` to make it a bit less verbose, and you will probably want to redirect it to a file.  Also you'll want to mark the places in the output that correspond to "before/after calling `basic-save-buffer`", since there'll be lots and lots of crap before that.

Comment: Not really what I was looking for, but this showed me that I was, in fact, only writing to the file once as desired.  The issue is that `watchmedo` is lying -- they aren't actually modify events.  `pyinotify` was able to confirm.